# Looking for specific arguments in text

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm looping through a number of .PHP files, treating them as plain text, and I'm attempting to locate text arguments of certain functions.

The functions in the PHP files are all called by using `\L10n::` and then take string arguments.

Examples of the text that I'm trying to find are below.

I've had the most luck at finding this correctly using the following regex lines.

```
pattern = re.compile("L10n::[\w]+\((?:\'(.*?)\')\,?\s?(?:\'(.*?)\')*", re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
```

OR

```
pattern = re.compile("\\L10n::(.*?)\('(.*?)'\)", re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)


bar\L10n::__('Double _')baz
bar\L10n::esc_attr__('Escape Attributes __')baz
bar\L10n::esc_html__('Escapted HTML __')baz
bar\L10n::_e('Echos')baz
bar\L10n::esc_html_e('Echo Escaped HTML')baz
bar\L10n::_x('Underscore X')baz
bar\L10n::_ex('Echo underscore x')baz
bar\L10n::esc_attr_x('Escape Attribute X')baz
bar\L10n::esc_html_x('Escaped HTML X')baz
bar\L10n::_n('Nothing')baz
bar\L10n::_nx('No X')baz
bar\L10n::_n_noop('N No-Op')baz
bar\L10n::_nx_noop('No X No-Op')baz
```

With that being said, some take multiple arguments

```
bar\L10n::_n('Text 1', 'Text 2', $variable)
```

In these instances I want Text 1 and Text 2, but not $variable.

To make it more fun... sometimes the arguments aren't all on one line.

```
bar\L10n::_n(
    'Text 1',
    'Text 2',
    $variable
)
```

The first regex pattern I had above fails if the text has an escaped ' inside it, such as 'This looks at people that weren\'t here'

The second regex patter I had above fails if there's multiple text variables. (It also brings up the _n section, but that's ok)

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I should also state, there will be other functions within the file, that I wish to ignore.

eg:

```
foo\file::__('function to ignore')
```

I don't want to match with these.

I also want to match for where the L10n functions are being used as arguments within other functions.

EG

```
bar\file::__(bar\L10n::_e('Text 1'), 'Other variable to ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try my hand at this one:

```
import re
input = """bar\L10n::__('Double _')baz
bar\L10n::esc_attr__('Escape Attributes __')baz
bar\L10n::_n(
    'Text 1',
    'Text 2',
    $variable
)"""
input = input.replace('\n', '')
reg = re.compile('\'(.*?)\'')
foo = reg.findall(input)
```

gives an array:

```
['Double _', 'Escape Attributes __', 'Text 1', 'Text 2']
```

Now what if you wanted to get fancy and index everything in a hash so that you could easily iterate over everything?

```
import re
input = """bar\L10n::__('Double _', 'another')baz
bar\L10n::esc_attr__('Escape Attributes __')baz
bar\L10n::_n(
    'Text 1',
    'Text 2',
    $variable
)"""
dict = {}
input = input.split('bar\\L10n::')
regName = re.compile('(.*)\(')
regAttr = re.compile('\'(.*?)\'')
for i in input:
    foo = regName.search(i)
    if foo is not None:
        dict[foo.group(1)] = regAttr.findall(i)
```

will make a dictionary that looks like:

```
{'__': ['Double _', 'another'], '_n': ['Text 1', 'Text 2'], 'esc_attr__': ['Escape Attributes __']}
```

Hope this helps!

There is a great website called [Rubular](http://rubular.com) that I use for regex, its supposed to be for Ruby but I use it for Ruby, Python and Perl regex. I suggest checking it out if you think you will be doing more regex stuff.

Edit: (After discussion in comments)

```
import re

globalDict = {}

for file in directory: # pseudo-code, implement this loop yourself

    fileContents = """bar\L10n::__('Double _', 'another')baz
    bar\L10n::esc_attr__('Escape Attributes __')baz
    bar\L10n::_n(
        'Text 1',
        'Text 2',
        $variable
    )"""
    regAttr = re.compile('\'(.*?)\'')
    for i in regAttr.findall(fileContents):
        if i in globalDict.keys():
            globalDict[i].append('filename')
        else:
            globalDict[i] = ['filename']
```

Comment: Thanks for that. 

I'm wanting a dictionary, so that much is easy, but I'm wanting it to be structured as follows:
`{'Double _ ':['filename_1','filename_2'],'Text 1':['filename_2', 'filename_3']..}

(Before I get to this code I'm looping through files, so I want to create a list of the files that the phrase is found in)

How would you change your code to suit this?

Comment: Use the regAttr regex and use those as the keys maybe? Sorry, I am not familiar with .PHP files.

Comment: See my other comment.

That's ok... it's a bit of a horrible thing to be search for! :(

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if that will work for your situation? Its slightly pseudo-cody but you should be able to fill in the rest.

Comment: Hmm, it's helped... Still a few little issues with it though. I know HOW many matches I should be getting, we've been using another program to do this in the past, but want to find a way to do this automated moving forward

Comment: What are the issues that its experiencing?

Comment: When a string had an escaped apostraphe, EG: `'This isn\'t picked up'` it picks up everything until the \

Comment: I've ended up using the following monstrosity in the regex for re.compile()

`(?:\\L10n::[\w]*\(\'(.*?)\'\,\s?(?:\'(.*?)\')*|\\L10n::(?:[\w]*)\(\n\t*\'(.*?)\'\,\n\t*(?:\'(.*?)\')*|\\L10n::[\w]*\(\n\t*\'(.*?)\'|\\L10n::[\w]*\(\'(.*?)\'\))`